# Is it safer to use a guest account when streaming from projectfreetv?

Tags: mac, virus

Hi I stream my tv shows from projectfreetv on my mac, but I was concerned about downloading a virus or something, so I started using my ''guest account'' when I stream, because it says when I logout all history will be deleted. Is this wishful thinking or do you think it helps to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In this [Top 10 list](http://www.isfym.com/top10/) (for Mac Internet security), one recommendation is:

> **Special bonus item (for advanced users):**
>
> **Consider running your Mac as a non-administrative user most of the time.** This is an advanced technique that provides few immediate
>   benefits, but, similar to anti-virus applications, acts as "insurance"
>   by limiting any damage that could result from a security breach.
>   Someone gaining access to your machine would still have access to many
>   of your files, but not to most of the underlying machine and OS
>   itself. **The easiest way to run as a non-admin user is to create a new,
>   administrative account and then change your normally used account to a
>   non-administrative one.**

This step would be part of a layered security approach, and probably could be applied to any OS - one wouldn't normally use an admin/root account in Linux, for example. Other sources endorse this approach as a security best practice (see [this forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=433497) and [this page](http://www.stanford.edu/group/security/securecomputing/mac.html) from the Stanford Secure Computing site).